# How to change glyphicon in my ajax render property's anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Just take a look at ajax : "target 0" : "render": "anchor tag"

I am using "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" initially.
i want to change it onclick to "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down".

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#PageNo").text(currentPage);
    tblErrorLog = $('#tblErrorLog').DataTable(
     {
         serverSide: true,
         ajax: {
             url: '@Url.Content("~/ErrorLogs/ErrorLogDataSaurce")',
             data: ErrorLogParameter,
             dataSrc: ErrorLogGridDataBound,
             type: "POST"
         },
         select: true,
         paging: false,
         searching: false,
         info: false,
         columnDefs: [
             {
                 targets: 0,
                 render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                     return '<a id=' + full.ID + ' onclick="return ViewErrorDetails(' + full.ID + ')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>'
                 }
             },
             {
                 targets: 1,
                 data: "Message",
                 orderable: true
             },
             {
                 targets: 2,
                 data: "Source",
                 orderable: true
             },
         ],

     });
});
```

Comment: also add your ViewErrorDetails() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your anchor should be like these.

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" id=' + full.ID + ' onclick="return ViewErrorDetails(' + full.ID + ', this)"></a>
```

And in function ViewErrorDetails() add this type of code.

```
function ViewErrorDetails(id, itm)
{
  $(itm).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
  $(itm).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-left');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect Way to do this work is..

```
<a style="color:#ccc" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" id=' + full.ID + ' onclick="return ViewErrorDetails(' + full.ID + ', this)"></a>

function ViewErrorDetails(ID, itm) {
    var tr = $('#' + ID).closest('tr');
    var row = tblErrorLog.row(tr);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
        $(itm).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
        $(itm).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        $(itm).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
        $(itm).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }

}
```

Comment: just show your answer related to question, not your whole function.

Answer (score 0):

I might have understood your problem wrong, but try this.

Give your anchor tag an id.

`<a id='anchor_sym'></a>`

Then, in `onClick()` method, do on of following:

```
/* Plain Javascript*/
var element = document.getElementById("anchor_sym");
element.className += " glyphicon-chevron-left";
element.className = element.className.replace("glyphicon-chevron-right", "");

/* Using JQuery*/
$('anchor_sym')
   .addClass('glyphicon-chevron-left')
   .removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
```